# SVN mergeinfo command returns revisions from other branches

Tags: svn, mergeinfo

I am running below command

**svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible --log svn:///svn/branches/16.1.3.x svn:///svn/trunk -R -v**

But, in the output, I am getting revisions from other branches like 16.1.1.x and 16.1.2.x, not a single revision from 16.1.3.x.
Whereas, if I do **Show Log** from **Merge** screen of the tortoise svn then I am getting revisions only of the branch 16.1.3.x.

I want same behavior from mergeinfo command. Please help.

Comment: `svn mergeinfo` does not support `(-v) --verbose` option, but there is one in your command. The command should not work with an error saying that there is invalid command-line option. And why do you specify `-R (--recursive)` option?

Comment: I am new to svn commands. I tried removing -R option but still getting revisions of other branches.